# Identify which type of Person Account record type it is from the Contact?

Tags: person-accounts

I have multiple types of Person Accounts in my org, using only the Contact object I want to identify which record type  my Contact record is. Using `Contact.RecordTypeId` appears blank when using Person Accounts so this cannot be used.

Is there another field available (similar to `PersonAccountID`) to get related Account information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not a field on the contact that tells you what the record type is. You would need to query the account instead (e.g. Account.RecordTypeId, etc). Note that it's probably better to just query the account instead, since you can access all the contact fields at the same time.